# `tsc` fails to compile .ts files to .js

Tags: typescript

I have an Express.js app that I haven't worked on for a week or so. After making some updates to the .ts files inside `src` and running `tsc` in the project root, I expect the .js files in the `compiled` folder to update. But they do not.

I am testing this by adding a console statement to the main file at `./compiled/server.js`. It does not print.

when running `tsc` I receive a new prompt with no feedback.

when running `tsc --watch` I see:

```
[9:51:13 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[9:51:17 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

Is something wrong with my configuration below?

If not, what else may be the issue?

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "outDir": "compiled"
  },
  "include": [
    "src", "__mocks__"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad adding `rootDir` and excluding the `compiled` folder has fixed the issue, thank you. If you would like to post an answer I will accept it